# Fixed search bar on tab template

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I'm using the tabs template of ionic. I need to be a fixed search bar, but I don't find how to insert this bar down the tabs bar.

My app is like:

[image: screen]
<sub>(source: [esfriki.com](http://esfriki.com/f/s01fb.png))</sub>

The problem is, I put the searchbar into the tab content, and this works, but, the bar is not fixed, when I do scrolling the list, the searchbar is scrolled too.

I need to have the tab nav-bar, and just down, before the lists (catalogs), the search bar (fixed).

Someone knows how I can do this?

tabs.html (tabs view):
https://paste.kde.org/pbqwtl473

tab-bynames.html (tab content):
https://paste.kde.org/pdxhlcviu

Sorry my poor enlglish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put search bar above `<ion-content>`, and instead of `bar-header` class, use `bar-subheader` class for search bar. Plus add class `has-subheader` to `<ion-content>`. Your code will be

```
<ion-view view-title="Buscar por nombres">
    <div class="bar bar-subheader bar-dark item-input-inset" no-tap-scroll="true">
          <ion-search placeholder="Buscar nombre" min-length="1" model="search"></ion-search>
    </div>
    <ion-content has-header="true" has-tabs="true" class="">
    //content part
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Now I have this: https://paste.kde.org/pscyzw244 and the search bar are disappeared.

Comment: Well, the search bar disappear because it's under the tabs bar. A dirty solution was set the top of search-bar on 93px (the top of content) and the content to 137px.

Comment: Hey @Exos what you realy need is this library, https://github.com/aliok/ion-affix